# Blackberry Listfield Item Separator

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I want add a separator in Blackberry Listfield inside drawListRow with graphics.drawLine Method but the Line is not being drawn at all below is source I am using

```
drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics g, int index,int y, int width) 
{
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Font f = g.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD,8,Ui.UNITS_pt);
    g.setFont(f);
    g.drawText (data[0], 10, y, Graphics.LEFT,Display.getWidth()); 
    f = g.getFont().derive(Font.SERIF_STYLE,6,Ui.UNITS_pt);
    g.setColor(0xC4C3C4);//light gray
    int h = f.getHeight() + 5;
    g.setFont(f);
    g.drawText (data[1], 13, y+h, Graphics.LEFT,Display.getWidth());
    g.drawBitmap( (Display.getWidth()- 30), y+7, this.rightIcon.getWidth(), this.rightIcon.getHeight(), this.rightIcon, 0, 0 );
    index = (index==0)?1:index;
    f = g.getFont().derive(Font.PLAIN,6,Ui.UNITS_pt);
    g.setColor(0xC4C3C4);//light gray
    g.drawLine(0, y+DIS_ROW_HEIGHT, Display.getWidth(), y+DIS_ROW_HEIGHT);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
g.drawLine(0, y+DIS_ROW_HEIGHT-1, Display.getWidth(), y+DIS_ROW_HEIGHT-1);
```

Comment: great -1 pixel for drawLine thnx

Comment: That is the height of the row. you can get it by calling listField.getRowHeight()

Comment: @rfsk2010 This is awesome! but the line did not show up in touch device(simulator) 9550 or 9930. Why? :(